# Rock Paper Scissors game loop

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a task to build a Stone,Paper,Scissors Game.
The game is supposed to run in 3 possible modes. best of 3 / best of 5 and endless games.

My code works fine until the point where I reset the game to begin a new game.
For a reason which I can not figure out, it plays multiple instances of my game, each time I call the game() function.
(after the game is over - a reset game button appears and the game mode needs to be reseleted)

I've added the entire project to this https://jsfiddle.net/vydkg3bz/, since I don't manage to pinpoint where the issue is.

I believe, due to all the extra logging I added, that the problem is somewhere in the game() function, as I tried to replace most of the code around it, with the same result.

Maybe someone has a moment to review my code and give me a hint where I should look?

````
// global variables
var choicesObj = {
  Rock: "url('./img/stone.png')",
  Paper: "url('./img/paper.png')",
  Scissors: "url('./img/scissors.png')",
}
var choices = Object.keys(choicesObj);
var moveAI;
var movePlayer;
var winnerRound;
var winnerGame;
var roundCount = 0; 

// actual game
function game(requiredWins) {
  console.log("game");
  enabler()

  var inputs = document.querySelectorAll(".inputButton");
  console.log(inputs);
  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    movePlayer = this.id
    handleClick(movePlayer)
    });    
  }

  // checking choice, display choice IMG, call compareChoices function 
  function handleClick(buttonID) {
    console.log("handleClick");
    moveAIfunc()
    movePlayer = buttonID;
    console.log('movePlayer: ' + movePlayer);
    console.log('moveAI: ' + moveAI);
    document.getElementById("mainImgPlayer").style.backgroundImage = choicesObj[movePlayer];
    document.getElementById("mainImgAI").style.backgroundImage = choicesObj[moveAI];
    compareChoices(moveAI,movePlayer);
    console.log("requiredWins", requiredWins);
    gameEnd();
    displays();
  }

  // AI control
  function moveAIfunc() {
    moveAI = choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length)]
  }

  // compare choices
  function compareChoices(a, b) {
    console.log("compareChoices");
    a = choices.indexOf(a);
    b = choices.indexOf(b);
    console.log("requiredWins", requiredWins);
    roundCount++;
    if (a == b) {
      winnerNone()
      return;
    }
    if (a == choices.length - 1 && b == 0) {
      winnerPlayer()
      return;
    }
    if (b == choices.length - 1 && a == 0) {
      winnerAI()
      return;
    }
    if (a > b) {
      winnerAI()
      return;
    }
    else {
      winnerPlayer()
      return;
    }
  }

  // game end
  function gameEnd() {
    console.log("gameEnd");
    console.log(requiredWins,winsPlayer,winsAI);
    if (winsPlayer == requiredWins) {
      console.log(requiredWins,winsPlayer,winsAI);
      winnerGame = "Player";
      disabler()
      createEndButton()
      return;
    }
    if (winsAI == requiredWins) {
      console.log(requiredWins,winsPlayer,winsAI);
      winnerGame = "AI";
      disabler()
      createEndButton()
      return;
    }
  }
}```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to be pretty complicated. The state of the wins/required wins etc. is not saved adequately in it. For playing you add event listeners *per game* (click), which is pretty inefficient imho.

I have created a mockup (a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) for the handling of games, using [`data attributes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) to remember the state of a game and [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) for the handling. Maybe it's useful for you.

Not related, but here's [my take](https://stackblitz.com/edit/scissorspaperrock?file=PlayFactory.js) on RPS.

```js
document.addEventListener(`click`, handle);

function handle(evt) {
  if (evt.target.id === `play`) {
    return play(evt.target);
  }
  
  if (evt.target.name === `nWins`) {
    return reset(evt.target);
  }
}

function reset(radio) {
    const value = radio === `none` 
      ? Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER : +radio.value;
    const bttn = document.querySelector(`#play`);
    const result = document.querySelector(`#result`);
    result.textContent = `(Re)start initiated, click [Play]`;
    result.dataset.wins = bttn.dataset.wins = 0;
    bttn.dataset.plays = 0;
    return bttn.dataset.winsrequired = value;
}

function play(bttn) {
    if (+bttn.dataset.winsrequired < 1) {
      return document.querySelector(`#result`)
        .textContent = `Select best of to start playing ...`;
    }   
    
    const result = document.querySelector(`#result`);
    bttn.dataset.plays = +bttn.dataset.plays + 1;
    const won = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
    const wins = +result.dataset.wins + won;
    result.textContent = `${won ? `You win` : `You loose`} (plays: ${
      bttn.dataset.plays}, wins ${wins})`;
    result.dataset.wins = wins;
    
    if (+bttn.dataset.plays === +bttn.dataset.winsrequired) {
      result.textContent = `You won ${wins} of ${
        bttn.dataset.winsrequired} games. Choose 'Best of' 
          to start another game`;
      bttn.dataset.plays = bttn.dataset.winsrequired = 0;
      result.dataset.wins = 0;
      document.querySelectorAll(`[name="nWins"]`)
        .forEach(r => r.checked = false);
    }
}
```

```html
Best of
<input type="radio" name="nWins" value="3"> 3
<input type="radio" name="nWins" value="5"> 5
<input type="radio" name="nWins" value="none"> indefinite

<button id="play" data-winsrequired="0" data-plays="0" >Play</button>

<p id="result" data-wins="0"></p>
```